# The Procedure Entry Point xyz could not be located / The Specified Procedure could not be found PHP ERROR with an extension

Tags: php, wamp, php-extension

The extension for php is grpc. It is aboslute hell. Firstly it would not discover the extension and now I have had to reinstall php like 5 times as well as a new install of WAMP. Now it discovers the file, it gives me "The specified procedure could not be found". I am running on PHP 7.3.12 64 bit on a thread safe system. I have downloaded both the latest version of grpc from pecl as well as an older one I thought would work. Rather, when I test the command prompt of the file (wampdir/php/php7.3.12/> php.exe --ini) it simply crashes with this error.

[image]

and then will print out in the terminal about not being able to find the procedure point. I have the correct system version but it simply will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow... To anyone in the future with this issue, reinstall wamp to the newest version. Checkout this kid's tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xK7q6aL_-4

Make SURE you have changed the php.ini files in wamp/bin/php/php.7.x.y/php.ini and wamp/bin/php/php.7.x.y/phpForApache.ini

If need be give the abosulte path.

I did this but I was using 7.3.10 but attempted the newest plugin version for my system type on 7.4.2. Dragged the right extension in. Changed the ini's to extension=grpc. I did not need to change extension_dir. Started wamp, changed php version and the errors went. Don't know how.